# Hybrid application: Change HTTP user agent header with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, http

I'm writing an hybrid app with Cordova and Ionic. My problem is that I want to access a server with an http request and I need to change the user agent of the device to pass a secret key.

```
 $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://my-server.com/service/',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent' : 'app_name/2.0 (iOS 8.1) secret=75456789087654', 
            }
     }).success(function(data){
        alert(data.content);
    }).error(function(){
        alert("error");
        });
```

But when I look at the logs of the server the user agent didn't change:

> "GET /service HTTP/1.1" - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac
>   OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome Safari" "https://my-server.com/service/"...

How can I change the header?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.
I think I'm going to create a Cordova plugin to handle http requests, and use it instead of $http. This way I have full control on headers I'm sending.